# Where could I put a ngx-toastr config file?

Tags: angular, toastr

I'm very new to Angular, and started working on some existing project.

It has `"ngx-toastr": "~10.0.2"` among the *package.json* dependencies, and I'd need to change some of its default parameters.

What I currently have :

```ts
this.toastr.success('Message');
```

What works for a single call :

```ts
  this.toastr.success('Message', null, {
    timeOut: 1000,
    extendedTimeOut: 1
  });
```

I couldn't find any place explaining how to change the default values. Neither here, nor in the tutorials I found.

Is it so obvious no one feels necessary to mention it ?  What did I miss ?

Comment: You can set defaults by passing in an object for .forRoot in your module..  example here: https://sebgroup.github.io/ngx-toastr/

Comment: @MikeOne Works like a charm !  Why not make it an answer ?

Comment: On my phone at the moment so a bit hard to create a properly formatted answer . No problem, if it helped you I’m happy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As MikeOne pointed out, the Angular modules config is located in app.module.ts

Here is a code sample from his link demonstrating how to do it:

```ts
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ToastContainerModule, ToastrModule } from 'ngx-toastr';
// [...]

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
// Default module configuration can be tweaked here //
    ToastrModule.forRoot({
      timeOut: 10,
      progressBar: true,
      positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right'
    }),
    ToastContainerModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
// [...]
```